# Use Go .Variable inside range block in THTML file

Tags: html, go, cgo, go-templates

I have a .thtml file:

```xml
...
<div>
    <p>{{.Something}}</p>        <!-- It works here! -->
    {{range ...}}
        <p>{{.Something}}</p>    <!-- It DOESN't work here! -->
    {{end}}
</div>
...
```

If I use the value of `.Something` inside the .thtml file it works fine, but it doesn't work if it is used in the same way inside a `{{range ...}}` block.

How can I use it?

Comment: I just have to change an existing Go application, but I don't have a technical background in this language. Also, I'll be thankful if someone can edit my question to make it more clear because I don't know the Go language terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor is modified by {{range}}.  Assign the cursor to a variable and use that variable inside the range.

```
...
<div>
    <p>{{.Something}}</p>        
    {{$x := .}}    <!-- assign cursor to variable $x -->
    {{range ...}}
        <p>{{$x.Something}}</p>    
    {{end}}
</div>
...
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/tQnOzB78VE)

If the starting cursor in this snippet is the starting value of the template, then use the `$` variable:

```
...
<div>
    <p>{{$.Something}}</p>     <!-- the variable $ is the starting value for the template -->    
    {{range ...}}
        <p>{{$.Something}}</p>    
    {{end}}
</div>
...
```

Comment: Based on this approach, if I just want to use the value for `Something`, is it better to have something like `{{$x := .Something}}` and inside the `{{range ...}}` block to use just `{{$x}}`?

Comment: The {{$x := .Something}} will have a very small performance benefit. I recommend using whatever makes the code easiest to understand.